# Lost formatting in custom Display Form

Tags: custom-list

I have a custom list with a rich text column, I created my own display form for the items so I could style them up a bit.  I noticed that the rich text column loses all it's formatting on the display form.  Is there anything I can do to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **rich text field** will contain html markup, which by default may be displayed "as-is" on the xslt view.

A solution for this problem - should this be the case - is to **render** the value of that field **as html** and not as plain text, which will cause the following example:

```
<div class="ExternalClass13B6DE041BA246688B35022ED990042A">
<strong>test markup</strong>
</div>
```

To be rendered as

**test markup**

Using the following code, which takes advantage of the [disable-output-escaping](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/el_value-of.asp) attribute

```
<xsl:value-of select="@Body" disable-output-escaping="yes" />
```

Comment: Perfect that's fixed it. Such a simple bit of code as well haha Cheers :)